# Terminal and Control panel shows different version of ruby

Tags: ruby, railsinstaller

I type `ruby -v` and this shows

```
ruby version 2.1.5p273
```

but in my control panel, ruby version is `2.2.1-p85`

I tried to change the version with `rvm use ruby-2.2.1` in the terminal but it returns 'rvm' as not internal or external command.

I am using railsinstaller btw

Comment: Are you on a Mac or Windows? Windows does not have RVM and a Mac does not have a Control Panel.

Comment: Its look like you are using `windows` PC. so `railsinstaller` not installing `RVM`. so rvm will not work.

Comment: oh i see.... may i know any leads how to update in windows?

Comment: There are version manager options for Windows, like Pik. (https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) I'm afraid, however, that your development experience will be quite miserable in Windows, and recommend you to switch if at all possible.